# Python wild card match

Tags: python, match, wildcard

I have a file like this

```
iPhone6-16GB-Black,40000,10000,10000,20000

iPhone6-16GB-White,40000,10000,10000,20000

iPhone6-16GB-Gold,40000,10000,10000,20000

iPhone6-16GB-Silver,40000,10000,10000,20000

iPhone6-16GB-Gray,40000,10000,10000,20000

iPhone6-64GB-Black,40000,10000,10000,20000

iPhone6-64GB-White,40000,10000,10000,20000
```

I need to search line by line and find all the lines that match the input

if input = iPhone6-*-*   It should match all lines with iPhone6-

if input = iPhone6-16GB-*  It should match all lines with iPhone6-16GB-

if input = *-*-*    It should match all lines

So far I have the code like this

```
for line in devLines:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.strip()
    if line and not line.startswith("#"):
        devName = line.split(",")[0]
        devName = devName.strip()
        if re.search(device, line) :
```

Comment: OK, so whats the problem?

Comment: What's the question? There's no question in this "question"...

Comment: In the input I get wild card like a star char and I need to search in the file and match for the wild card. For eg the line if re.search(device, line) : does not match all the lines if there is a wild card like \*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Get search input from the user.
2. Open and reader file by `csv` module.
3. Check first item from each row with search text.
4. Print result.

code:

```
import csv

search_text = raw_input('Enter search text:').strip()

file2 =  '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/file3.txt'

with open(file2) as fp1:
    root = csv.reader(fp1)
    if search_text=="*":
        result =  list(root)
    else:
        result = [i for i in root  if search_text==i[0]]
        #result = []
        #for i in root:
        #   if search_text == i[0]:
        #       result.append(i)

print result
```

output:

```
Enter search text:*
[['iPhone6-16GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'], ['iPhone6-16GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'], ['iPhone6-16GB-Gold', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'], ['iPhone6-16GB-Silver', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'], ['iPhone6-16GB-Gray', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'], ['iPhone6-64GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'], ['iPhone6-64GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]

vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:iPhone6-16GB-Gray
[['iPhone6-16GB-Gray', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]

vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:test
[]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```

---

By **regular expression** and according to modification of question.:

Create regular expression of search text.

code:

```
import csv
import re
import pprint

file2 =  '/home/vivek/Desktop/stackoverflow/file3.txt'

def searchText(search_text):
    print "search_text:", search_text
    with open(file2) as fp1:
        root = csv.reader(fp1)
        result = [i for i in root  if re.findall(search_text, i[0])]

    return result

search_text = raw_input('Enter search text:').strip()
#validate input
try:
    tmp1, tmp2, tmp3 = search_text.split("-")   
    search_text = search_text.replace("*", "[^-]*")
    result = searchText(search_text)
    pprint.pprint(result)
except:
    print "wrong search text. *-*-*"
```

output:

```
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:*-*-*
search_text: [^-]*-[^-]*-[^-]*
[['iPhone6-16GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-Gold', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-Silver', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-Gray', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-64GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-64GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:iPhone6-*-*
search_text: iPhone6-[^-]*-[^-]*
[['iPhone6-16GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-Gold', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-Silver', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-16GB-Gray', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-64GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-64GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:iPhone6-64GB-*
search_text: iPhone6-64GB-[^-]*
[['iPhone6-64GB-Black', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-64GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:iPhone6-64GB-White
search_text: iPhone6-64GB-White
[['iPhone6-64GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$ python 30.py 
Enter search text:iPhone6-*-White
search_text: iPhone6-[^-]*-White
[['iPhone6-16GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000'],
 ['iPhone6-64GB-White', '40000', '10000', '10000', '20000']]
vivek@vivek:~/Desktop/stackoverflow$
```

Comment: What would happen if this is the input 
Enter search test = iPhone-\*-\*

[root@ip-172-31-26-130 genLogs]# python testwildcard.py
Enter search text:*-16GB-*
[]
[root@ip-172-31-26-130 genLogs]#

Comment: yes its not handle.. give some time.. I think you updated question for this??

Comment: Thanks a lot Vivek. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Shawshank: Can you check now?

Comment: Vivek, works like a charm for all kinds of wild card input. Thank a lot my friend, awesome stuff.

Comment: @Shawshank:  Welcome. Can you up vote and accept answer if this is helpful to you. :) I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fnmatch.translate` which takes shell like wildcards and converts them to a regex string which can be used with `re.compile` to create a matcher that can be used to filter your results:

```
import re
from fnmatch import translate as wc_to_re

search_for = raw_input('Search for: ') + '*'
is_match = re.compile(wc_to_re(search_for), flags=re.I).match
with open('yourfile') as fin:
    for line in filter(is_match, fin):
        print line, # or do something else appropriate?
```

The matching is case insensitive, so entering: `iphone6-16gb*` will print the following:

```
iPhone6-16GB-Black,40000,10000,10000,20000
iPhone6-16GB-White,40000,10000,10000,20000
iPhone6-16GB-Gold,40000,10000,10000,20000
iPhone6-16GB-Silver,40000,10000,10000,20000
iPhone6-16GB-Gray,40000,10000,10000,20000
```

And `iphone6-16gb-g*` will give:

```
iPhone6-16GB-Gold,40000,10000,10000,20000
iPhone6-16GB-Gray,40000,10000,10000,20000
```

Comment: Thanks Jon. This works for most of the wild card combinations. But does not work if there is no wild card in the search string like "iPhone6-*-Gold" or "iPhone6-16GB-Black"

Comment: @Shawshank added a `+ '*'` to the `raw_input` - that should work.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean? Please be more specific.

The file I used. (test.txt)

```
name-12-100
name-12-200
name-24-100
name-36-100
```

The code.

```
from re import search

ipt = 'name-12'

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if search(ipt, line):
            print line
```

'name'

```
name-12-100
name-12-200
name-24-100
name-36-100
```

'name-12'

```
name-12-100
name-12-200
```

'name-12-200'

```
name-12-200
```

Comment: How to i do this for ipt = name-\*-100 or ipt = \*-\*-100  or ipt=\*-\*-*